# Javascript pick winner from random numbers with percentage

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, percentage

Im very sorry if the title is a little bit misleading!

So basically i have this:

Example 1:

```
var array = [30,30,30]
```

or Example 2:

```
var array = [10,50,20]
```

I need to pick a winner from these numbers with percentages. Example: 50 wins 5 times more often than 10.

I have solution for that but it doesnt really work and is inaccurate.
Update: This solution doesnt have anything to do with what i really want.

```
var array = [10,50,20];
var totalValue = 80;

array.sort();
array.reverse();

var lowestNumber = array.slice(-1)[0];
total += lowestNumber;

var random =  Math.floor((Math.random() * total) + lowestNumber );

  array.some(function(entry) {
 if (entry < random) {
  console.log('winner', entry)
  return true;
 }
})
```

This script is working on the second example, but 20 has a way to higher chance to win and the first example of course doesnt work at all.

Im happy for every answer / comment!

Comment: Do you want the winning chance ratio to be the same as the value in the array? Eg 50 wins 5 times as often as 10? Or, what do you want?

Comment: yes thats exactly what i need, ill update the question.

Comment: I'm not sure the duplicate answer has a great solution to this problem..  I would do things different to that,..  First normalize your distribution from 0 to 1 incremented,.  eg.  `10,50,20`  would become -> `0.125,  0.75, 1`,  now just do a normal random, and then reverse step into the array until this random number is greater than the array value...

Comment: Thats a step forwards! but what 30,30,30 would become and how?